# complex datatable should be created by select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, join

I need to write an sql select statement and I got stuck. I am trying to write an sql for a complex GRID. The grid is supposed to be used to enter budget values.

here is the way my grid is supposed to look like. you can see that there are MAIN rows, and each main row has 4 child rows. I need to produce the same from the select statement
[image]

Unfortunately, my select statement produces the datatable as below

```
SELECT TYPE,
   NO,
   DESCRIPTION,
   ISNULL((SELECT VALUE FROM RN_BUDGET_INVEST_VALUES V WHERE  V.BUDGET_ID=40 AND V.FIRMA_ID=2 AND V.DEPARTMENT_ID=200 AND V.MODULE_ID=6 AND V.YEAR=2013 AND V.COLUMN_INDEX=1 AND V.ROW_INDEX=1 AND V.CREATED_USER=1),0) AS 'OCAK',
   ISNULL((SELECT VALUE FROM RN_BUDGET_INVEST_VALUES V WHERE  V.BUDGET_ID=40 AND V.FIRMA_ID=2 AND V.DEPARTMENT_ID=200 AND V.MODULE_ID=6 AND V.YEAR=2013 AND V.COLUMN_INDEX=1 AND V.ROW_INDEX=1 AND V.CREATED_USER=1),0) AS 'ŞUBAT',
   ISNULL((SELECT VALUE FROM RN_BUDGET_INVEST_VALUES V WHERE  V.BUDGET_ID=40 AND V.FIRMA_ID=2 AND V.DEPARTMENT_ID=200 AND V.MODULE_ID=6 AND V.YEAR=2013 AND V.COLUMN_INDEX=1 AND V.ROW_INDEX=1 AND V.CREATED_USER=1),0) AS 'MART',
   ISNULL((SELECT VALUE FROM RN_BUDGET_INVEST_VALUES V WHERE  V.BUDGET_ID=40 AND V.FIRMA_ID=2 AND V.DEPARTMENT_ID=200 AND V.MODULE_ID=6 AND V.YEAR=2013 AND V.COLUMN_INDEX=1 AND V.ROW_INDEX=1 AND V.CREATED_USER=1),0) AS 'NİSAN',
   ISNULL((SELECT VALUE FROM RN_BUDGET_INVEST_VALUES V WHERE  V.BUDGET_ID=40 AND V.FIRMA_ID=2 AND V.DEPARTMENT_ID=200 AND V.MODULE_ID=6 AND V.YEAR=2013 AND V.COLUMN_INDEX=1 AND V.ROW_INDEX=1 AND V.CREATED_USER=1),0) AS 'MAYIS',
FROM RN_BUDGET_INVESTMENT_VARIABLES VARS
```

[image]

I dont know how to create the child rows. can you give me an iade?

Comment: How are you looping in your grid? I think thats more important

Comment: that s a good question. I just want to bind the datatable that comes from the select statement to the grid. I am not sure if I made it clear for you?

Comment: Can you show code on how you are looping through grid? How are you binding that grid?

Comment: gridControl.DataSource = myDatatable;   //mydatatable is the result of the select statement

Comment: i came accross the same type of question which is answered just within a weeek in stach over flow, please search that

Comment: thanks Anto, believe me, I made a lot of searching but coulnt get a hint from stackoverflow or google. I believe I am very unlucky today on searching :) would you please give me a link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would like to do a RIGHT OUTER JOIN to get it to look slightly similar.
Also you must join on the foreign key relation between the tables, like BudgetNr or FIRMA_ID or CREATED_USER or some relation between the tables.
Also your WHERE statements all return the same data, so you need to change them as all have the same BUDGET_ID, FIRMA_ID, DEPARTMENT_ID,MODULE_ID, YEAR, COLUMN_INDEX, ROW_INDEX, CREATED_USER

```
     SELECT TYPE,
        NO,
        DESCRIPTION,
        ISNULL(V1.VALUE,0) AS 'OCAK',
        ISNULL(V2.VALUE,0) AS 'ŞUBAT',
        ISNULL(V3.VALUE,0) AS 'MART',
        ISNULL(V4.VALUE,0) AS 'NİSAN',
        ISNULL(V5.VALUE,0) AS 'MAYIS',

     FROM RN_BUDGET_INVESTMENT_VARIABLES VARS
     RIGHT OUTER JOIN RN_BUDGET_INVEST_VALUES V1 ON V.[LinkKeyto RN_BUDGET_INVESTMENT_VARIABLES table] = [LinkedKey in this table] WHERE  V1.BUDGET_ID=40 AND V1.FIRMA_ID=2 AND V1.DEPARTMENT_ID=200 AND V1.MODULE_ID=6 AND V1.YEAR=2013 AND V1.COLUMN_INDEX=1 AND V1.ROW_INDEX=1 AND V1.CREATED_USER=1
     RIGHT OUTER JOIN RN_BUDGET_INVEST_VALUES V2 ON V.[LinkKeyto RN_BUDGET_INVESTMENT_VARIABLES table] = [LinkedKey in this table] WHERE  V2.BUDGET_ID=40 AND V2.FIRMA_ID=2 AND V2.DEPARTMENT_ID=200 AND V2.MODULE_ID=6 AND V2.YEAR=2013 AND V2.COLUMN_INDEX=1 AND V2.ROW_INDEX=1 AND V2.CREATED_USER=1
     RIGHT OUTER JOIN RN_BUDGET_INVEST_VALUES V3 ON V.[LinkKeyto RN_BUDGET_INVESTMENT_VARIABLES table] = [LinkedKey in this table] WHERE  V3.BUDGET_ID=40 AND V3.FIRMA_ID=2 AND V3.DEPARTMENT_ID=200 AND V3.MODULE_ID=6 AND V3.YEAR=2013 AND V3.COLUMN_INDEX=1 AND V3.ROW_INDEX=1 AND V3.CREATED_USER=1
     RIGHT OUTER JOIN RN_BUDGET_INVEST_VALUES V4 ON V.[LinkKeyto RN_BUDGET_INVESTMENT_VARIABLES table] = [LinkedKey in this table] WHERE  V4.BUDGET_ID=40 AND V4.FIRMA_ID=2 AND V4.DEPARTMENT_ID=200 AND V4.MODULE_ID=6 AND V4.YEAR=2013 AND V4.COLUMN_INDEX=1 AND V4.ROW_INDEX=1 AND V4.CREATED_USER=1
     RIGHT OUTER JOIN RN_BUDGET_INVEST_VALUES V5 ON V.[LinkKeyto RN_BUDGET_INVESTMENT_VARIABLES table] = [LinkedKey in this table] WHERE  V5.BUDGET_ID=40 AND V5.FIRMA_ID=2 AND V5.DEPARTMENT_ID=200 AND V5.MODULE_ID=6 AND V5.YEAR=2013 AND V5.COLUMN_INDEX=1 AND V5.ROW_INDEX=1 AND V5.CREATED_USER=1
```

You might also like to look at [PIVOT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx). I think that is more what you are looking for.

Comment: there is a syntax problem that I cannot fix, it says there is a problem near at the second "RIGHT" keyword